# Visual Studio Code shortcut equivalent to Webstorm / IntelliJ Extend Selection

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, webstorm

I've grown accustomed to Webstorm's "**Extend Selection**" shortcut which grows the selection to the next special character.

Example (if the cursor is somewhere in the "someObjectProperty"and the shortcut is activated):

```
var foo = someObject.someObjectProperty.subProperty;
                     <-- selection 1 -->
          <------ selection 2 --------->
          <-------------- selection 3 ------------>
```

Now that I've switched to Visual Studio Code, the closest to that type of shortcut I've found is '**editor.action.smartSelect.grow**' shortcut

However, while it is similar, it's not the same. Using the same example (if the cursor is somewhere in the "someObjectProperty" and the shortcut is activated):

```
var foo = someObject.someObjectProperty.subProperty;
       <---------------- selection 1 -------------->
<------------------- selection 2 ------------------>
```

Is there anything similar in VS Code as the **Extend Selection** in WebStorm as described above?

Comment: **FYI:** [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857846/vs-code-select-word-at-caret-shortcut-like-in-webstorm-ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857846/vs-code-select-word-at-caret-shortcut-like-in-webstorm-ide)

Comment: **Also** This is what we need - https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/extend-selection/ - unfortunately current VSCode do not emulate this feature the same way.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The Feature you're looking for is called shrink-expand-selection.

It works by using:

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to select the next sections

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> to select the previous sections

It works as follows for your example (imagine the cursor being on the j of someObjectProperty):

```
var foo = someObject.someObjectProperty.subProperty;
                         <-S1-> (This section exists because of camelCase)
                     <-    S2        ->
          <-               S3        ->
          <-               S4                    ->
<-                         S5                     ->
```

For reference:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_shrink-expand-selection

Comment: Why is this marked as the best answer? This is not the feature you're looking for (Jedi ). It does not give the right solution. From what I saw there is no IntelliJ "extend selection" equivalent in VS Code. As another answer says there is a plugin for it though.

Comment: Hi Alpâr, thanks for leaving a comment. I legitimately don't understand the Downvotes to my answer. I looked at IntelliJ's extend selection and "Shrink / expand" in VS Code does excatly this for me (and seemingly the person asking the question as well). My only guess at this point is that other Systems than Windows require different Keyboard Shortcuts. Please double check the link I provided to the VS Code Docs.

Comment: for me it didn't work with the default shortcut (ctrl+shift+right arrow), but "expand selection" with other key bindings works great

Comment: IntelliJ `CTRL-W != Shift+Alt+[Left/Right-Arrow]` of VSCode. :-(

Comment: A visual hint for what is requested is here - https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/extend-selection/ - unfortunately current VSCode do not emulate this feature the same way.

Comment: So I got to this SO question as a die-hard IJ user, just _trying_ VSC and to get any work done, "extend selection" is a must-have. Keybindings been a nightmare to port and cross-reference. At first, I was thinking everyone else was right, this isn't the same thing. And they're right. It's close, but after a side-by-side comparison, the noticeable differences for me are, if the cursor begins in a multi-word PascalCase, CamelCase or snake_case word, you've got an extra key-tap to get out of it. kebab-case has some weird behavior that causes 2nd-tap to select a lot more than expected.

Answer (score 9):

While there is no such shortcut/command that comes with VS Code there is third party extension that can be easily installed:

```
ext install expand-region
```

More info on the **expand-region** command:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=letrieu.expand-region

Answer (score 1):

There's still no such thing, the third party plugins are nowhere near what Webstorm/Idea does, here's an incomplete [visual gap analysis](https://github.com/windwp/vscode-expand-region/issues/23) on how they can't be mentioned on the same page.