# VS Code 'Select word at caret' shortcut like in WebStorm IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, visual-studio-code

**WebStorm IDE** has a very useful [shortcut](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206819745-Do-You-Use-The-Ctrl-W-Keyboard-Shortcut-) for selecting text by combination **Ctrl + W**;

It easy to put cursor for example to one of the arguments in function and press combination twice for select all arguments, first press will select one argument, second - all. And then if you press again, IDE will select all function.

```
function foo(a, b, c) {}
```

- *first press*: selected **b** (for example)
- *second*: selected **a, b, c**
- *third*: selected **function foo(a, b, c) {}**

Summarise, selection increases depending on number of presses shortcut.

**VS Code** [has](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics) shortcut **Ctrl+D** which can select only one argument.

Does anyone know how to add smart selection like in WebStorm to VS Code?

Comment: Like this: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/extend-selection/ - unfortunately current VSCode do not emulate this feature the same way.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is possible without an extension with the command "Expand select", `editor.action.smartSelect.grow`, which by default is `"ctrl+shift+cmd+right"`

Comment: Just an FYI for others coming to this question after using IntelliJ IDEA products - This was not an adequate solution using VS Code 1.22.1. Try this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings

Comment: @mark Barely adding shortcuts to mimic some defaults in JetBrains IDEs doesn't do the trick when expand select itself in VSCode works in a slightly different way.

Comment: @KamenMinkov exactly. Has anyone found a solution to mimic JetBrain's behavior 100%?

Comment: @aviggiano From what I read, the dev team want the scope resolution to rely language's own server; I've found that it works quite well for TypeScript, but not that well with JSON for example.

Comment: After a while I've grown used to using `editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch` (for me bound to `Alt+J`), which from the first press selects just the current word (even if it's in camel case) - i.e. even if it sounds counterintuitive, it won't select more matches unless you invoke it a second time.

Comment: I'm using linux, so the idea of @KamenMinkov really works. The shortcut is Ctrl+D.

Answer (score 17):

As a comment suggested I tried out https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings

However, the only real bind that I wanted was the grow and shrink selection commands. That extension will overwrite a lot of the default VScode keybinds. To get *just* the grow and shrink selections, edit your `keybindings.json` file adding the following lines:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+w",                
  "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.grow",
  "when": "editorTextFocus" 
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+w",
  "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.shrink",
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

*edit: Using version 1.26.1

Comment: if you cant find keybidings.json go to FIle->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts in the top is line: For advanced customizations open and edit keybindings.json

Answer (score -2):

This is not supported natively but is possible via extensions.

For example the [Hot Commands](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.HotCommandsforVisualStudio) extension

> **Edit.IncreaseSelection**
>
> Expands the current text selection by one level
> (ie. next largest code block level)    Ctrl+{, Ctrl+}
>
> **Edit.DecreaseSelection**
>
> Shrinks the current text selection by one level
> (ie. next smallest code block level)   Ctrl+{, Ctrl+{

More suggestions in [this previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906593/visual-studio-editor-extend-selection-to-the-next-larger-code-block)

Comment: Thanks, it help me to found another [extentsion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings). It is port of IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: That's a nice one, i'll actually try it out.

Comment: This is not really relevant - your answer targets Visual Studio when the question is about VSCode.